# HttpsURLConnection status code 302 when establishing a connection

Tags: java

I am trying an example on httpsURLConnection,I get the following exception

Status code: 302

```
ejava.lang.IllegalStateException: connection not yet open
```

Following is the code snippet :

```
  private static String url_s = "https://java.sun.com:443" ;

   URL url = new URL(url_s) ;
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection() ;
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET") ;
        conn.connect() ;
```

Comment: Try different URL like http://google.com

Comment: Nothing wrong with the program. Try with different URL it works.

Comment: The url is getting redirected.so, the connection is not yet open

Comment: thanks Vinay, I Changed the url works fine now.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read up a bit about HTTP protocol first if you really wanna try your hands at direct client calling.

302 is temporary redirect header which is sent back from the server. The response has another header named 'Location' whose value is a URL to which the server wants you to hit next. Browsers handle this automatically so you dont see a wait thing.

But if you want to do it yourself be sure ot handle all 301, 302 situations like these.

Best Of Luck.